# Sequelize v5 : FindAll in the then of Create doesn't retrieve created row

Tags: sequelize.js

Hello everyone,
I have a problem with Sequelize v5, with a MySQL database.  
When I try to perform a findAll on a model after performing a Create, I don't have the model just created. 
What should I do to solve this problem?  
 
Here's the problematic code, and what it does:  
I create an actor, I link it to an association table, then I do a findAll. I'm sure that the actor is well created (present in BDD, same with association table, 'Commit' displayed in console, and I have the return id of the actor created before the findAll).

```
return Actor.create({
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
    mobile: req.body.mobile,
    email: req.body.email,
    city: req.body.city,
    zipcode: req.body.zipcode
  }).then(function (rowCreated1) {
    return Asso_role_school_actor.create({
      id_actor: rowCreated1.id_actor,
      id_role: 1,
      id_school: req.body.id_school
    }).then(function () {
      return Actor.findAll({
        attributes: ['id_actor', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'mobile', 'city', 'zipcode'],
        include: [{
          model: Asso_role_school_actor,
          where: {
            id_role: 1,
            id_school: req.params.id_school,
            finishAt: null
          },
          attributes: []
        }]
      }).then((results) => {
        console.log(results);
        return res.status(200).send(results);
      });
    });
  });
```

All leads are welcome ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the object using req.body.id_school but in the include of find method you use req.params.id_school. Maybe this is causing the trouble?

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not the problem :( 
It happens to me in other request too